# ¿hay algo similar al método iloc en pandas que pueda usar en el modulo csv en Python?

Tags: python, csv

¿hay algo similar al método `iloc[]` en pandas que pueda usar en el modulo csv en Python?
o podrían decirme cual es la forma más común de acceder a una columna y una fila especifica de un `archivo.csv` al mismo tiempo sin usar pandas?

Lo pregunto ya que solo necesito acceder a un elemento especifico de mi `archivo.csv` y no quiero tener que importar todo pandas para únicamente usar el método `iloc[]`

```
def cargar_tareas(self):
    with open("registro_tareas.csv", "r",encoding = "UTF-8") as archivo:
        reader = csv.reader(archivo)
        numero_filas = len([reader])
        numero_columnas = len(next(reader))
        # next nos da la primera fila de un archivo.csv y si usamos len son dira la cantidad de columnas que tiene

    if numero_filas > 0:
        lista = []
        for fil in range(0, numero_filas):
            for col in range(0, numero_columnas - 1):
                self.tareas.append(reader[fil, col])
```

en esta ultima línea estoy intentando acceder a una fila y una columna especifica.

```
self.tareas.append(reader[fil, col])
```

Comment: @pinta34
al intentar usar tu código me da el siguiente error: self.tareas.append(archivo[archivo["titulo"] == numero_columnas]) ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una forma de acceder a elementos específicos de mi `archivo.csv` con `csv.DictReader(archivo)`.
lo que hace `csv.DictReader(archivo)` es convertir todo nuestro `archivo.csv` lo que luego nos permite acceder a esté como si fuese un diccionario `indice_fila["nombre_columna"]` ej: `row["titulo"]`

```
with open("registro_tareas.csv", "r+",encoding = "UTF-8") as archivo:
        reader = csv.DictReader(archivo)
        numero_filas = len([reader])

        if numero_filas > 0:
            for row in reader:
                nueva_tarea = Tarea(row["titulo"], row["descripción"], row["fecha de creación"], row["fecha de vencimiento"])
                self.tareas.append(nueva_tarea)
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Equivalencia

El modulo csv es un modulo mucho más simple que pandas. Su unico proposito es crear un objeto que va procesando cada linea del csv convirtiendola en una lista de cadenas, o generar el csv a partir de la lista antes mencionada.

En base a esto, la tecnica más simple es convertir este objeto en lista y acceder a la fila y columna por POSICIÓN, y guardar los cambios una vez finalizado. Por supuesto, implica cargar todo el csv en memoria (cosa que pandas hace de todas formas)

```
reader = csv.reader(archivo)

# Opcional: convierte el nombre de una columna en su posición en la lista de cadenas.
# Si consideras innecesario este diccionario, es obligatorio poner 
# next(header), lo cual nos permite evitar considerar el encabezado como una fila.
colname_to_pos = {col:pos for pos, col in enumerate(next(reader))}

# procesamos las lineas pendientes y las guardamos en una lista.
lines = list(reader)

segunda_fila = 1
columna = colname_to_pos["columna"]

lines[segunda_linea][columna] = "1"

...
```

Esto utiliza funcionalidades basadas en los iteradores (csv.reader devuelve un iterador). Entender este concepto te ayudará a entender mejor esta respuesta.

Por supuesto, podés crear una clase o función que te ayude a leer el csv.

##### Nota aparte

Dependiendo el escenario, te va a convenir más usar pandas o csv. En mi opinión, si es para hacer un programa simple, te conviene el modulo csv. En cambio, si necesitas funciones de base de datos más complejas, te convendrá más pandas. Vos elegís según lo que te convenga, no te bases al 100% en otras opiniones como la mía, considera lo mejor para tu escenario.

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilizar el siguiente método:

```
df[df['nombre'] == valor]
```

En este caso, el dataframe se llama df, la columna nombre y la búsqueda específica será valor

Comment: La pregunta indica que no quiere usar pandas. Además, en todo caso si usase pandas, sería más eficiente usar iloc de por sí.